# How to tell if a windows PE file is a console subsystem or a windows subsystem programmatically?

Tags: windows, winapi, console, exe, portable-executable

Basically I need a program that will sort windows .exe's from the console counterparts.

A file scanner:

```
SortExe(file exe) 
{
 if (IsPeWindows(exe)) 
    {
      AddToList1(exe); 
    }
 else if (IsPeConsole())
    {
    AddToList2(exe); 
    }
 }
```

How do I implement IsPeWindows or IsPeConsole() ?

I do not particularly mind what language solutions come in so long as it's one of c, c++, c# or visual basic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `SHGFI_EXETYPE` to [`SHGetFileInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) & examine the hi/loword of the return value as explained in the link.