# How to detect Console or Windows Application?

Tags: c, windows, console

I am trying to write a icon changing program like resource hacker. I am able to change icons of windows programs but not console programs and I think thats quite obvious. So I want to write a code in my program that will check if the argument exe file is a console program or windows program before it tries to change the icons.

So how do I check if an exe file is a console program or windows program. I am writing program in C using visual studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if a windows PE file is a console subsystem or a windows subsystem programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739571/how-to-tell-if-a-windows-pe-file-is-a-console-subsystem-or-a-windows-subsystem-p)

Answer (score 2):

The `Subsystem` value inside the [Portable Executable header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) of the file will give you the info:

```
WINDOWS_CUI  3 Runs in the Windows character subsystem (a console app)
```